# Run commands remotely on a GCP machine

Tags: python, linux, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-compute-engine

I want to run commands remotely **from** a GCP instance **to** another one, using a Python script on a Debian machine.

I know that the gcloud ssh command can do that with the subprocess module, but I don't know how to proceed faster as it creates a new key each time I run the command. Is there a way to operate with a service account for example, on which I could setup permissions and keys for each machine on my GCP project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a SSH Key in your "source" machine

```
ssh-keygen
```

And then add your public key into the `ssh keys` tab on the metadata page on Google Cloud Console, under the settings category, from the Compute Engine section.

Then, you should be able to log in to the other instance doing

```
ssh [user@]other_instance_ip [optional command to execute]
```

Comment: Thanks. But in my script or in the command, is it possible to specify the user I want to use for ssh? Should I do that with a service account or a user account? I was thinking about user@instance, but i'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, you can specify the user exactly like you say, preppending user@ to the instance name.